# loginButtons slow to load in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm using accounts:password and the {{ > loginButtons }} for authentication in Metor. The problem is that the loginButtons template isn't initilaized until Meteor has polled the collection and got the values on initial page load. This can take several seconds.

Is there a way to fix this, e.g. by forcing meteor to poll the collection at inital load, or similar?

Comment: I've never had this problem, so I think more code could help clarify what is causing the delay. The only collection accounts talks to is users.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details about your application, there is a package called `meteorhacks:fast-render` https://github.com/meteorhacks/fast-render which could be helpful since it renders the HTML without waiting for the data.

Comment: I've tried adding fast-render, but I need to supply a waitOn function for the routes. I don't know which subscription I should wait on to wait for the loginButtons...